# Seaborn violin plot with a colorscale

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

Let say I have the following violin plot :

```
df = sns.load_dataset("titanic")
sns.violinplot(data=df, x="class", y="age", hue="alive", split=True, inner="quart")
plt.show()
```

[image]

I would like to to add a dimension by adding a color scale that would be give each semi-violin a color according to the average "fare" for each group. Any idea of how I could do that please?

Thanks a lot!
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could compute the average fare per class/alive, translate this into a color (e.g. using a diverging palette) and inject the color to the violin's facecolor:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection
from matplotlib import cm

df = sns.load_dataset("titanic")

# compute average
# order of the groups is important
# it should match the order of the violin halves
avg = df.groupby(['class', 'alive'])['fare'].mean()

# plot with custom extreme colors
# can be extracted using:
# sns.diverging_palette(220, 20, n=2).as_hex()
ax = sns.violinplot(data=df, x="class", y="age", hue="alive",
                    split=True, inner="quart",
                    palette=['#3f7f93', '#c3553a'])

# set up colormap, assign colors from average fare
# fares matching the group 'alive="no"' are set as negative values
cmap = sns.diverging_palette(220, 20, as_cmap=True)
MAX = avg.max()
norm = Normalize(-MAX, MAX)
colors = cmap(norm(avg.mask(avg.index.get_level_values('alive')=='no', -avg)))

# update colors
for color, violin in zip(colors, ax.findobj(PolyCollection)):
    violin.set_facecolor(color)

# add colorbar and use absolute values as tick labels
cb = plt.colorbar(cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap))
cb.set_ticklabels(abs(bar.get_ticks()))
```

Output:

[image]

```
# avg
class   alive
First   no       64.684007
        yes      95.608029
Second  no       19.412328
        yes      22.055700
Third   no       13.669364
        yes      13.694887
Name: fare, dtype: float64
```

Comment: That works well, thanks a lot! How can I add the corresponding colorbar? I tried using 'ax.figure.colorbar(sm)' but the scale doesn't look right...